# LightDm command doesnt work in shell script

Tags: scripts, lightdm

I found a script that checks when the lid close, and tried to make him lock the screen.
I tried the code below first, it works, but it turned out to be somthing I don't want. (The code checks if the lid is close, if yes- it does `systemctl suspend`)

```
if [ "${1}" -eq 1 ]; then systemctl suspend 
fi
```

I checked what was the right command for what I need and tried to put it in:

```
if [ "${1}" -eq 1 ]; then dm-tool switch-to-greeter 
fi
```

When I tried it, nothing happened (The command works in the terminal, but not in the script).
Does anybody know how to fix it / other command that does the same?

Comment: try with full path of binary dm-tool `/usr/bin/dm-tool`

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the full script.

Comment: Thia is the full script, do you mean to add the other file that call this script? @dessert

Comment: Im new to this OS, can you please tell me what to write (/create) and where? @cmak.fr

Comment: Check if dm-tool is installed `whereis dm-tool` - If present, write `/usr/bin/dm-tool` where you wrote `dm-tool`

Comment: Didn't work, still does nothing. 'if [ "${1}" -eq 1 ]; then /usr/bin/dm-tool switch-to-greeter fi' @cmak.fr